# Removing repeated elements in a list of words and counting the number of repetitions

Tags: matlab, sorting

This is my code, I am trying to sort an array of words, and calling the sorted array 'a'.
I am trying to use a while loop to compare adjacent elements of a, and as it is sorted any repetitions should already be next to each other. If there is a repetition I remove the word and and it to the count. I am unsure how to get my output to show each sorted word and its associated count together. Thank you for any help.
(myAsort is a function I have already made that puts words into alphabetical order)
For example if I input myACsort({'cat','dog','cat'), I want the output to be:

```
answer = 
    'cat'     'dog'
    count:2   count:1

function [ answer ]= myACsort( input )
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
a = myAsort(input);
n = length(a);
i = 1;
count = 1;
while (i<=n)
    if isequal(a{i},a{i+1})
        a(i+1) = [];
        count = count+1;
    else
        count = 1;
        i=i+1;


    end

end



end
```

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The usual combination of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) would be my suggestion:

```
>> strs = {'cat','dog','cat'};
>> [uStr,ia,ic] = unique(strs);
>> countCell = [uStr(:).'; num2cell(accumarray(ic,1)).']
countCell = 
    'cat'    'dog'
    [  2]    [  1]
```

FYI, you can later extract the counts via `counts = [countCell{2,:}];`.

---

If you wan to do it without the help of these functions, you can fix up your `myACsort` function as follows:

```
function answer = myACsort(input)
a = sort(input); % sort operates on cell arrays of strings
i = 1; count = 1;
uwords = a(1);
while (i<numel(a))
    if i<numel(a) && isequal(a{i},a{i+1})
        a(i+1) = [];
        count(i) = count(i)+1;
    else
        i=i+1;
        count(i) = 1;
        uwords(i) = a(i); 
    end
end
answer = [uwords(:).'; num2cell(count(:)).'];
```

Although array growing is not very efficient.

Comment: +1 I love to see `.'` used properly instead of `'`:-)

Comment: What does `.'` do? I've never seen this syntax.

Comment: @jerad That's the element-wise transpose. Without the dot, it's the [complex conjugate transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html). The difference only really matters with complex data, but it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: sort the strings (variable `sortedStrs`), detect the end of each run of equal strings in the sorted sequence (variable `ind`), and the result is easily obtained from that.

```
strs = {'cat','dog','cat'}; %// data
n = numel(strs);
sortedStrs = sort(strs);
dif = arrayfun(@(n) ~strcmp(sortedStrs{n},sortedStrs{n-1}), 2:n);
ind = [ find(dif) n ];
result(1,:) = sortedStrs(ind);
result(2,:) = mat2cell([ind(1) diff(ind)],1,ones(1,numel(ind)));
```